# How can I instantly get the result of my produced event in kafka and kafka-streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I am simplifying my problem with the following scenario:
3 friends share a loyalty card. The card has two restrictions

1. can be used max 10 times (does not matter which uses the card, ie
   friend_a can use it 10 times.
2. the max money in the card is 200. So with 1 "event" of value = 200 the card is "completed".

I am using a kafka producer that sends events in the kafka cluster like this

> {   "name": "friend_1",   "value": 10 }
>
> {   "name": "friend_3",   "value": 20 }

the events are posted to a topic that is connected with a kafka stream that groups by key and doing aggregation to sum the money spent. That seems to work, however I am facing a "concurrency issue"

Let's imaging the card is used 9 times, so only 1 time remains to be used and the total money spent is 190, that means there are 10 units left to spend.

So friend_2 wants to buy something that costs 11 units (which should not be allowed) and friend_3 wants to buy something that costs 9 units which should be allowed. Friend_3 will modify the state using the card for the 10th time. All other future attempts should not modify something.

So it seems reasonable for the card user to know if the event he sent modified the max used number and the total count. How can I do it in kafka? Using the streams aggregation I can always increase the values, but how can do I know if my action "modified the state" of the card?

UPDATE: the card user should immediately get a negative feedback if the transaction validates a rule.

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand your question there are a few options.

One option is to derive a new stream after the aggregation that you `filter()` for data that would modify 'the state' of the card, like filtering all events that have `> 200` units spent or `> 10` uses. This stream can then be used to inform the card user(s) that the card has been spent, e.g. by sending an email.  This is approach can be implemented solely with the DSL.

When more flexibility or tighter control is needed, another option is to use the Processor API (which you can integrate with the DSL so most of your code could keep using the DSL), where you implement the aggregation step yourself (working with state stores that you attach to a `Transformer` or `Processor`). During the aggregation, you can implement the logic that checks whether the incoming event is valid (in your example: friend_3 with 9 units is valid, friend_2 with 11 units is not). If it is valid, the aggregation increases the card's counters (units and uses), and that's it. If it is invalid, the event is discarded and will not modify the counters, the `Transformer`/`Processor` can emit a new event to another stream that tells the card user(s) that something didn't work.  You can similarly implement the functionality to inform users that a card has been fully used, that a card is no longer usable, or any other 'state change' of that card.

Also, depending on what you want to do, take a look at the [interactive queries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) feature of Kafka Streams.  Sometimes other applications may want to do quick point lookups (queries) of the latest state of something, like the card's state, which can be done with interactive queries via e.g. a REST API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Michael, my case requests an immediate response to the card user if the transactions is go or "no go". The email notification, even a few seconds later, is not the case here.

Comment: When you use an event streaming setup (like with Kafka), you opt for an architecture that is, primarily, asynchronous rather than synchronous.  So I'd recommend to think again about your 'immediate response' requirement.  (Is it sync request/response? Is some async delay acceptable, if yes, how much?)